# how to create a regex to remove multiple characters?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to create a single expression that will work for both branch1 and branch2 below?I need to remove the words -dev and -rel from branch,how can I do that?

```
chars_to_remove = ['-dev','-rel']
branch1 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-dev'
branch2 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-rel'
component = branch1.translate(None, ''.join(chars_to_remove))//should work for both branch1 & branch2
print component
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:(for both branch1 and branch2)-

```
bt.lnx.2.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print (branch1.replace('-dev','').replace('-rel',''))

print (branch2.replace('-dev','').replace('-rel',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

chars_to_remove = ['({}.*)'.format(i) for i in chars_to_remove] 

def trimmer(your_string):
    return re.sub(r'|'.join(chars_to_remove),'',your_string)

print trimmer(branch1)
print trimmer(branch2)
```

Output:

```
'bt.lnx.2.1'
'bt.lnx.2.1'
```

Comment: what if I want to remove `-dev.*` and '-rel.*` ,anything after -dev and -rel needs to be removed?

Comment: this logic fails for `com-devices.lnx.1.0-dev`,the output is `com`,it should be `com-devices.lnx.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

use `regex`, it remove `chars_to_remove` at end of string, remove the `$` from the regex if you wanna remove all the match including match at middle also

```
import re
chars_to_remove = ['-dev','-rel'] # modify char to remove here
def remove_char(s):
    return re.sub("({})$".format('|'.join(chars_to_remove)), '',  s)

branch1 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-dev'
branch2 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-rel'
remove_char(branch1) # 'bt.lnx.2.1'
remove_char(branch2) # 'bt.lnx.2.1'
```

Comment: I think hardcoded regex isn't quite for this usecase. If OP added a new extenstion to consider (for example `rpm`), would you add it in your regex? Is it a good solution? Specially when OP already formed a list, you should consider the list while writing the solution.

Comment: @Ahsanul Haque, updated, now its quite close to your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If they're always at the end you can simply use string slicing.

```
if branch[-4:] == '-dev' or branch[-4:] == '-rel':
     branch = branch[:-4]
```

If they're not all at the end, you might want to use the re module.

Comment: What if  the portions to strip aren't of same length? (Not a downvoter).

Comment: @Ahsanul Good point. From the wording of the question, it seemed to me like OP is only interested in the specific cases mentioned so I didn't think varying lengths would matter here. Definitely something to consider. Thanks.